# Is it considered bad practice to throw NotSupportedExceptions in derived classes?

Tags: inheritance, notsupportedexception

Sometimes people want to hide a method in a derived class but don't want to violate the Liskov Substitution Principle, so they leave it in there and instead throw a `NotSupportedException`, possibly with a comment that this method throws.

Isn't such practice just as bad if not worse in the sense that it shifts the problem from a compile-time issue to a runtime issue if people don't go about reading every comment on every method before passing around derived classes?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that if a subclass does not support a method in its superclass then as a rule it probably should not be extending that class. Beyond requiring runtime checks to handle possible exceptions like you mentioned (which could be a problem in cases where optimizing for performance is necessary), however, I think the bigger issue with this approach would be that it shifts responsibility from the subclass to every classes that needs to use it, making your software less encapsulated and as a result harder to maintain and reason about (which becomes bigger issues the bigger the software gets).

That being said, this question is inherently subjective. If this approach works for you, by all means do it. I personally prefer simple APIs over complicated ones, but that's me.